# Setting Margin between TableRows

Tags: html, css, margin, html-table

I'm trying to set certain margin between two table rows.

I'm using following code snippet in **css**:

```
background-color: #72c2dd;
margin-top: 25px;
```

`background-color` gets applied but `margin-top` **doesn't work**. (refer below screenshot)

This is the issue with whole table.
All other properties are working properly but there is some issue with `margin`.

Any help appreciated.

[image]
Image on the left is **how it should be** and the image on the right is **how it is getting displayed** (without margin top to the second row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table cells do not have margins to change. You can, however, change the padding of the cells. Another trick you could try would be adding a transparent border to the upper part of the row using something such as:

`border-top: 5px solid transparent;`

Comment: I tried `border-top-width:25px;
 border-top-color:green;
 border-top-style:solid;` (of course I'll use color:transparent afterwords), but this doesn't work...

Comment: but if I try this code for another element, it works... STRANGE :(

Comment: Are you using this as inline CSS or in a stylesheet? Did it have any effect all?

Answer (score 1):

Use border-top instead, border-top: 25px solid white original try table-layout http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp and set custom height to that cell

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one column then **"cellspacing"** will solve the problem;

Or else you can use a white top border for rows of width 25px;